# How can I add html to alchemy.js captions

Tags: d3.js, alchemy.js

Is it possible to add html elements such as `<tspan>` inside the caption of a node in Alchemy.js?

My alchemy config has the following:

```
nodeCaption: "title",
```

and if I have json like:

```
{
  "nodes": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "title": "Some <tspan>text</tspan>",
      ...
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

The caption on the graph will render as `Some <tspan>text</tspan>`...

FYI: I am happy to take suggestions that require making manual changes to the alchemy.js file. I've already had to make some of my own changes for other things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within the `DrawNode` function in alchemy.js replace

```
.text(function(d) { ...
```

with

```
.html(function(d) { ...
```

Now `<tspan>` will render in a node caption.